# Redirecting user based on his authentication

Tags: react-native, axios

In my react native application, I want to check if a user has already logged in before, then he must be redirected to 'Home' directly without asking him for credentials again. The 'Home' component consists of logout button in a sidebar.

My current code works fine for new user logging, but I am stuck on how to check if again the user open the application, his login token should persist and he must be redirected to 'Home' directly.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View, Image, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, AsyncStorage, ToastAndroid } from 'react-native'
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Login extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super();

        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            isLoggedIn: false,
            loginChecked: false,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getItem('userID');
    }


    //function to extract storage token. Any name can be given ot it. 
    async getItem(item){
        console.log('method ran login screen');
        console.log(this.state.isLoggedIn)
        try{
            const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(item);
            if(value !== null){
                this.setState({
                    isLoggedIn: true,
                    loginChecked: true
                })

            }
            else{
                this.setState({
                    isLoggedIn: false,
                    loginChecked: true
                })
            }
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
        console.log(this.state.isLoggedIn)
    }

    //function to remove storage token 
    async removeItem(item){
        try{
            const value = await AsyncStorage.removeItem(item);

            if(value == null){
                this.setState({
                    isLoggedIn: false
                })
            }
        }
        catch(error){
            //handle errors here
        }
    }



    userLogin = () => {

        if(this.state.username != '' && this.state.password != ''){
            axios.post('http://bi.servassure.net/api/login', {
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password
        })
        .then(res => {

            let userToken = res.data.token;
            console.log(res.data);

            if(res.data.success){
                AsyncStorage.setItem('userID', userToken);
                this.setState({
                    isLoggedIn: true
                })
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
            }
            else{
                ToastAndroid.showWithGravity(
                    'Invalid login' ,
                    ToastAndroid.SHORT,
                    ToastAndroid.CENTER
                  );
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });

        }
        else{
            ToastAndroid.showWithGravity(
                'Please Enter Credentials' ,
                ToastAndroid.SHORT,
                ToastAndroid.CENTER
              );
        }
    }


    logOut(){
        this.removeItem('userID');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                <View style={{justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>

                    <View style={{marginVertical:20}}>
                        <Text>
                            Login to your account
                        </Text>
                    </View>


                    <View>
                        <TextInput 
                            style={{width: 300, height: 50, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, borderRadius: 10, marginVertical: 10}}
                            onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({username})}
                            placeholder='username'
                            autoCapitalize = 'none'
                        />

                        <TextInput 
                            style={{width: 300, height: 50, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, borderRadius: 10}}
                            onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
                            placeholder='password'
                            secureTextEntry={true}
                        />
                    </View>

                    <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                        <TouchableOpacity 
                        style={{width: 300, height: 50, borderWidth:1, borderRadius: 50, borderColor: 'gray', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginVertical: 10}}

                        onPress={this.userLogin}>

                            <Text>
                                LOGIN
                            </Text>

                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <Text>Forget Password</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}
```

Also, I have a SplashScreen before login:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'

export default class SplashScreen extends Component {

    componentDidMount(){

        setTimeout( () => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')
        }, 2000)

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.viewStyles}>
                <Text style={styles.textStyles}> My App </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}


const styles = {
    viewStyles: {
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      backgroundColor: 'orange'
    },
    textStyles: {
      color: 'white',
      fontSize: 40,
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
  }
```

I am bit new to react native, please help to figure this out.

Comment: Store the token somewhere (redux, file system,...) and once the user comes back, just redirect if the token is still valid (not expired).

Comment: Can you provide me some snippet for it. Without redux?

Comment: You can check the token each time the app becomes 'active' using AppState from react-native. You need to attach a listener in componentDidMount. Something like `AppState.addEventListener('change', (nextState) => { // if nextState === 'active' check your token and act accordingly })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this in your **Login.js** file:

```
import {AsyncStorage} from react-native;
```

After getting the response success of login API you can do this:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('userID', responsejson.user_detail.userID);
```

in the same way, you can store the token also

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('token', responsejson.user_detail.token);
```

Then in your **splashscreen.js**, import AsyncStorage the same way as above and then place this code in **componentWillMount() or componentDidMount()**

of your **splashscreen.js**

```
 var value =  AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    value.then((e)=>{

    if (e == '' || e == null ){
         this.props.navigation.replace('Login')          
    }else {
       this.props.navigation.replace('Home')
    }
    })
```

***Explanation***: When splashscreen.js is loaded then it checks for the token in asyncstorage and if it gets the token navigate to Home screen else navigate to Login screen.

Comment: Thanks it worked. But One problem is still occurring. When I click back from home screen, it shows Splash Screen. Then again on second back, it exits from the app. How to resolve this?

Comment: use this.props.navigation.replace('screen_name') in place of navigate

Comment: It gives error: replace is not a function.(In 'replace('Login')', 'replace' is undefined.

Comment: this.props.navigation.replace('screen_name') use this

Comment: and don't forget to import stackactions from react-navigation before using `replace`

Comment: @bubble-cord use these import {StackActions} from 'react-navigation';
import {NavigationActions} from 'react-navigation';

Comment: @bubble-cord why did you removed my answer as correct answer? Did my answer not helped you?

Answer (score 1):

Import the React Navigation library and use the Switch Navigator. It was designed to handle app navigation based on the login status of the user.

[This article explains everything with examples](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html)